# Plots in ggplot2 appearing without grey background

Tags: r, ggplot2

I just used ggplot2 earlier and all my plots are appearing without the grey default background. I am not sure why its doing that because it was working two weeks ago and I have not touched R since then. Not sure if its a bug in R or on my part.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(cowplot)
p1=ggplot(health,aes(Smoker,Pulse))+geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(Smoker)))   +geom_jitter()
p1
```

[image]

Before I use to get the background with the grey tiles and this what I am getting above. Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Loading `cowplot` changes the default layout of `ggplot2`. Check out the `cowplot` [introduction](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html):

> I prefer a clean and sparse layout for publication. I also prefer the approach of building a graph by adding elements rather than taking
>   them away. Therefore, the default design of cowplot has no grid at
>   all. It looks similar to ggplot2’s theme_classic(), but there are a
>   few important but subtle differences, mostly with respect to font
>   sizes.

**PS:** adding `theme_grey()` to your plot should return it to the `ggplot2` default

Comment: `theme_set(theme_grey())` will restore the default setting.