# cowplot masking ggplot2 even after detaching

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I'm having a problem with `cowplot` as I created several graphs using `ggplot` but as soon as I load `cowplot` I can no longer obtain the same plot rerunning that ggplot script. I detached `cowplot` using `detach(package:cowplot)` and when I search for it using `(.packages())` it is no longer listed. However, when I restart the session and do not load `cowplot` and run my `ggplot` script, everything is fine. Anyone else experiencing this issue? Both packages are the newest versions--`ggplot2 2.2.1` and `cowplot 0.9.1`.

Comment: `detach(package:cowplot, unload = T)`

Comment: I think you need `detach(package:cowplot, unload=TRUE)`. `cowplot` sets the ggplot theme elements to different values. However, after loading `cowplot`, instead of detaching it, you can also just reset the ggplot theme to whatever you want. For example, `theme_set(theme_bw())`.

Comment: @Gregor This is a duplicate, but it's a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096293/cowplot-made-ggplot2-theme-disappear-how-to-see-current-ggplot2-theme-and-res).

Comment: Thanks Claus! I couldn't find a post that answered my question, but I appreciate the find!

Comment: Ah, right you are. Even unloading cowplot doesn't reset the theme. Unfortunately I can't change marked duplicate.

Comment: It can be removed (click the "edit" button in the lower right of the "duplicate" message), but maybe it's better to just keep both links available.

Comment: I think it's clearer that the relevant duplicate be the only one listed, given Claus comment and the reply from the OP. I have therefore made this change to the duplicates.