# drawing multiple ggplots objects in one single page in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have several ggplot objects called p1,p2,p3,p4. 
I wouldd like to plot them all in one page. To do so I am creating a list of ggplots:

```
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, p4, labels = "AUTO")
```

This command plots all of them but it changes the theme and background and other details of my single original plots.

Do you know how can I plot them together without loosing any feature of original plots? 
Thanks

Comment: Please check my inclusion of `library(cowplot)`. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: Very likely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096293/cowplot-made-ggplot2-theme-disappear-how-to-see-current-ggplot2-theme-and-res/41096936#41096936